# Usefulness of government reported "market value"

Tags: real-estate, housing

My county's property records often indicate a "market value" along with tax assessments. This is typically lower than the listing price of property, and I'm wondering how to interpret it.

For example, I saw one home listed on Zillow at 450k. The property record gives a "2023 Market Value" as 280k, and even specifies 40k land + 240k improvements.

Having viewed the home, I indeed think that the fair price for it would be no more than 300-350k, even accounting for the recent market events. Coincidentally, the seller has listed the property at almost exactly the same price as Zillow's Zestimate. The Zestimate has recently jumped up in price, although the last time it was 280k was early 2021.

The county's website states that the "market value" is based on recent sales of similar properties. Digging a bit deeper, they mention using a Computer Assissted Mass Appraisal (CAMA) program. I have never seen this CAMA, but this sounds like a reasonable and objective way to figure out the actual fair market values of houses.

Based on this, it seems like the county's "market value" is a good indicator of true value. Therefore if the listing price is much higher and the seller is unwilling to negotiate, it is probably unwise to actually purchase that property. Of course, most listings are significantly higher than the government's value, but one would expect that the properties listed for a good price sell quickly while those with inflated asks linger.

---

There is a similar question, but its answer https://money.stackexchange.com/a/52557/122663 does not apply to my case:

- I am asking about the market value, not assessed value. For reference, the assessed value for this house is 27k, so it is clearly unrelated to value.
- The county updates market values every year. It does not reassess "every three years (Maryland)".
- The county clearly states that they base the market value on similar sales and they do not mention anything about capping the increases.

Comment: Suggestion: Call the county clerk's office and ask them to explain what this number means. They probably have the answer; at worst they will know who reports it and be able to tell you who to ask.

Comment: @keshlam Why would I call the clerk for this? They already explain what the number means on their website and I noted it in the question. Besides, I'm not asking what the government claims about their assessment. I'm asking if it's a good indicator of how much the house is actually worth.

Comment: I don't think it is.  Town assessment is a _very_ shallow look at overall condition combined with size and a few other numbers to try to guess which recent sales were comparable. It should be in the general ballpark... unless your town skews the numbers for tax purposes, or there is something more, or less, attractive about your place than the assumed comparables. The market may be different than it was for the comparables, they may have been lucky it unlucky in finding the right buyer... The value is what that particular customer is willing to pay and you are willing to accept.

Comment: Note that price is also affected by how long you can afford to wait for a better bid. Sometimes closing the deal sooner is worth a considerable amount.

Comment: @keshlam I get that it's tempting to say "oh well they just make it up for taxes" and then there's no need to actually answer the question. But they don't. I think your point about it being shallow is more sensible, but if the issue was merely precision as you say, it would be off in either direction. However, in practice it is more or less below the listing price. This seems to me more consistent with the county's value indeed being a good measure of value, and the sellers characteristically over-asking to fish for the proverbial greater fool, and to leave a "haggling buffer".

Comment: I strongly suspect this is true in some places but not others.... and actual sale price varies much more widely and rapidly than assessment does, in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

They're useful, depending on what use you have. The county values are the ones used to calculate the property taxes.

The county assessors usually use automated calculations - i.e.: they don't actually go to each property and evaluate it like mortgage appraisals do, they use statistics about the area and the information about the property listed in the county database (which may not be up to date if there were some changes or improvements done without permits, or cosmetic repairs make it look much better than other similar houses). Amount and frequency of transactions in your area can affect this as well (too few and far apart make it much less precise than frequent transactions with clustered valuations per property type).

A couple of more things may significantly affect the values (although you mentioned these don't apply to you).

- They may be skewed depending on how the county assessments work. For example, in California the county assessors can only raise the assessed value 2% a year, no matter what the market does. So you may end up with properties valued at millions of dollars on the market, but valued at thousands of dollars by the county and taxed accordingly. This is the result of the [California Proposition 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1978_California_Proposition_13) from the seventies. Other areas may have different rules which may similarly affect how the county assessors operate.
- Another thing to remember is that county assessors may not reassess every year. In some areas reassessments are done every several years and may lag behind the market quite significantly (in either direction, but people would usually appeal much faster if the market goes down). You're saying that that's not the case in your specific county.

Similarly Zestimate is some automated statistical calculation that doesn't take the specifics of the house into the account. But that is even less precise because it purely relies on data aggregation, and may be potentially manipulated by the owners and real estate agents (using phantom MLS listings or self-reporting data to Zillow).

In the end, in a sale transaction the value is what the seller is willing to accept and the buyer is willing to pay.

---

One thing I didn't mention, until you pressed a bit more in the comments: staleness of the data.

Zestimate is fed constantly and may change on a daily basis (and some less ethical agents are using that to try and manipulate it similarly to SEO).

County records are updated at best annually, and usually the valuation is set about half a year before it comes into effect for the actual tax assessment. So your county data is much more stale, even if it is much more precise *when calculated* compared to Zestimate. In a real estate market, information about transactions from 1.5-2 years ago reflected in the *current* valuation for property taxes may not be very relevant to an actual current sale transaction. The market may have moved since, and by a lot, in either direction.

Comment: +1. Any assessment, even one where they crawl through the whole house in detail, is at best a ballpark guess. What you can actually get for it depends on your patience, the mood of the economy, how much it looks like the potential buyer's dream home, what your neighborhood is like (on many axes), and (as far as I can tell) whether Saturn is in the house of Jupiter and plans to stay for dinner.

Comment: There's some interesting information in this question, but I don't get the point. So is the government assessment a good indicator of fair market value, or not? If I go around offering sellers to buy their house at "market value", will I eventually close a fairly-priced sale, or will this be a hopeful exercise of low-balling?

Comment: I'm confused here. It feels like you're talking about a completely different pair of Q-A. What are you talking about with spam offers? I'm saying the house is listed as for sale and obviously the seller is expecting offers. If you're talking about "luck" and saying the seller would be "dumb" to accept an offer at the county-reported market value, does that mean you think the market value is generally an unrealistically low valuation? We seem to be have a radically different understanding of how price discovery works in free markets. Incidentally, I'm asking about a free market, not California.

Comment: And why would the seller contest it? This is just a market value, not the tax assessment value.

Comment: @gomennathan sorry, I misunderstood you. I'll delete that comment. So you're asking if the seller listed the price at 450K would it make sense to offer 280K? You'll probably want to discuss it with your agent who'd know the market in your area much better. I'd say if the house was *just* listed, it is unlikely that the seller would accept an offer ~40% below asking. But if it was sitting there for a year - what's the worst that can happen?

Comment: @littleadv Ah, thank you - yeah, I think now you got me. Well, obviously I can discuss it with my agent, but I'm asking what people here think. As for seller accepting it, maybe they will, maybe not. This one seller is irrelevant, I just gave some numerical examples to make it more concrete. The question is, is there generally a reason to expect that some non-trivial fraction of sellers would accept the "market price", given that it is ostensibly derived from *similar transactions*?

Comment: @gomennathan I don't think this question is answerable in a generic way. Listing price is a good indicator of what the seller *wants*. Recent transactions are a good indicator of what other buyers *paid*. The county valuation is lagging by at least a year, though, so I don't know how valuable it is as a data point for consideration of a specific transaction.

Comment: So if I'm trying to figure out what I should pay, isn't it better to look at what others paid, rather than look at what the seller wants? Sellers want all kinds of things, there's not really rhyme or reason to it, especially in this market. I don't really want to base my offer on what the seller wants. I want to base it on what a normal person would pay for it (incidentally, I expect to sell to that normal person later). Seems like "what other buyers paid" is a pretty useful number here.

Comment: @gomennathan what others paid is important because that's your competition. You don't want them to outbid you, so you'll want to offer in the same ballpark *at least*. But, what the seller wants is what the seller wants. I've seen cases where the sellers wanted something the market was unwilling to offer. So they waited. Eventually they got the offer they wanted. Again, you'll need to talk to your agent, different markets behave differently and specific sellers can have different motivations which your agent, if they're good, will find out. In the end - it is a much guessing game.

Comment: @littleadv Why would I care if they outbid me? This seems to be a strange logic which results in me stubbornly engaging in every bidding war without any consideration. I want to figure out the actual value of the house and bid that. If someone else bids higher, let them get ripped off. It's not my problem - plenty of other houses out there, and I'd rather not buy than overpay. If the county's figure is an aggregation of similar sales, it is logically impossible that everyone overpays. As for agent, again, I'm not asking my agent. I'm asking users of the site.

Comment: @gomennathan you're weird. If someone pays more then you - it means that your offer was too low and didn't reflect the actual value. They end up getting the house that *you* wanted. What's the goal of the exercise? To purchase a property. How do you get their? By convincing the seller to sell to you, and not to anyone else. How do you do that? By offering them more money than anyone else. What's the value of the  house? The amount the seller agreed to sell for. That's all, nothing else.

Comment: The goal is of course not to purchase a house at any price. Lots of people do not wish to pay more for a property than it's worth. Nothing weird about it.

Comment: @gomennathan that's a meaningless statement

Comment: It is not, though perhaps the meaning escapes you.

Comment: @gomennathan no, it doesn't. You *think* that there's some magical number that represents the actual value of the property and are trying to guess what it is so that you don't pay "more than that" and feel "ripped off". But there's no such number.

Comment: I know full well what I think, thank you. I am not interested in debating the existence of "fair market value" with you. I would downvote the question if I could.

Comment: no worries, helped you there.